# How do I change the amount of space set aside on the hard drive for deleted files?

Tags: hard-drive

How do I change the amount of space set aside on the hard drive for deleted files?

Comment: Operating system?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, right-click the Recycle Bin icon and select Properties.  There you can set the maximum size of the Recycle Bin for each of your hard drive partitions.  Your deleted files will consume this space until you Empty the Recycle Bin.